# Como colocar uma caixa de texto em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar uma caixa de texto(input) em javascript, para ser mais específico, dentro de uma determinada célula de uma tabela (gerada através de uma matriz). 
Desde já...J.G.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body onKeyDown="pegadirecao(event.keyCode);">
<div id=principal></div>
<script>
tabuleiro="<table align=center border=1>";
 for(x=0;x<2;x++)
 { tabuleiro+="<tr>";
  for(y=0;y<5;y++)
  { tabuleiro+="<td id=td"+x+"_"+y+" style='width:70px; height:70px;'></td>";
  }
  tabuleiro+="</tr>";
 }
tabuleiro+="</table>";
document.getElementById('principal').innerHTML=tabuleiro;
 </script>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body onKeyDown="pegadirecao(event.keyCode);">
<div id=principal></div>
<script>
```

Comment: Coloca o código dessa matriz.

Comment: rray, acabo de colocar o código!

Comment: Sempre coloque o código e a descrição do problema ou dúvida assim fica facil para o pessoal ajudar vc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo do que você está querendo Fazer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Alterar celula 0,0</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0];
    x.innerHTML = "<input type='text' >";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Eduardo Binotto, cara, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @J.Gaidzinski, eu que fico feliz em poder ajudar. Se puder marcar minha resposta como a melhor fico agradecido. Obrigado.